# ${\text{Show that}}:{a_{2n}} - {a_{2n - 1}} = a_n^2 - a_{n - 1}^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this problem
$$\eqalign{
  & {\text{Consider a sequence is given by}}:  \cr 
  & {a_0} = 1,{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n} = \frac{{{a_n} + \sqrt {5a_n^2 - 4} }}{2}  \cr 
  & {\text{Show that}}:{a_{2n}} - {a_{2n - 1}} = a_n^2 - a_{n - 1}^2 \cr} $$

I tried to used mathematical induction

$$\eqalign{
  &  * n = 1 \Rightarrow {a_2} - {a_1} = 5 - 2 = 3 = {2^2} - 1  \cr 
  &  * {\text{Suppose }}\left( 1 \right){\text{ is true for }}n = k \geqslant 1,{\text{ we need to prove }}\left( 1 \right){\text{ is true for }}n = k + 1  \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow {a_{2k + 2}} - {a_{2k + 1}} = a_{k + 1}^2 - a_k^2  \cr 
  & {\text{We have}}:{a_{2k + 2}} - {a_{2k + 1}} = \frac{{3{a_{2k + 1}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k + 1}^2 - 4} }}{2} - \frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4} }}{2}  \cr 
  &  = \frac{{3\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right) + \sqrt {5{{\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right)}^2} - 4} }}{2} - \frac{{3\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k - 1}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k - 1}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right) + \sqrt {5{{\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right)}^2} - 4} }}{2}  \cr 
  &  = \frac{{3\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4}  - 3{a_{2k - 1}} - \sqrt {5a_{2k - 1}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right)}}{2} + \frac{{\sqrt {5{{\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right)}^2} - 4}  - \sqrt {5{{\left( {\frac{{3{a_{2k}} + \sqrt {5a_{2k}^2 - 4} }}{2}} \right)}^2} - 4} }}{2} \cr} $$

But it seems lead to nowhere. Can you please give me a hint to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do not delete a question just after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find it hepful.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$a_{n+1}^2-3a_{n+1}*a_n +a_n^2 = -1 \\ $
then we also gonna have by swapping the index by one
$a_{n}^2-3{a_n}*a_{a_{n-1}}^2+a_{n-1}^2 = -1 $

$a_{n+1} = a_{n-1}$ or $a_{n+1}+a_{n-1} = 3a_n$ since the sequence is increasng we have the second one $a_{n+1} +a_{n-1} = 3a_n$

then just use characteristic equation and simple elimination and substitution to prove that $a_n = F_{{2n}+1}$ where $F_{n}$ is the Fibonacci sequence